# [Solved]Magento 1.9 Override RoundPrice

Tags: price, magento1.9.3, rounding

Vers. Magento 1.9.3.9

I need to override thi function from Mage_Core_Model_Store

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
    return round($price, 2);
}
```

So I created e new module:

app/etc/modules/MyCompany.xml

```
<config>
     <modules>
        <MyCompany_RoundPrice>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                 <Mage_Core />
            </depends>
       </MyCompany_RoundPrice>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/MyCompany/RoundPrice/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyCompany_RoundPrice>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MyCompany_RoundPrice>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <roundprice>
        <class>MyCompany_RoundPrice_Model</class>
      </roundprice>
      <core>
        <rewrite>
          <store>MyCompany_RoundPrice_Model_Store</store>
        </rewrite>
      </core>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/MyCompany/RoundPrice/Model/Store.php

```
<?php

class MyCompany_RoundPrice_Model_Store extends Mage_Core_Model_Store
{
    public function roundPrice($price)
    {
        return round($price, 4);
    }
}
```

It should work but it doesn't.

What is wrong???

**EDIT**

Some tests:

```
echo Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('MyCompany_RoundPrice').'<br />'; //output 1
echo Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('MyCompany_RoundPrice').'<br />'; //output 1
echo Mage::getModel('roundprice/store')->roundPrice(1.23456789); //output 1.2347
echo Mage::getModel('core/store')->roundPrice(1.23456789); //output 1.23
```

The module is active and reachable, but doesn't override the core file.

Comment: I think you should create same folder structure like core means in your local folder create core->mage->store then put your files there it should work.

Comment: Sure, but than i'll override the whole class, not just that function

Comment: yes exactly you can go through this link too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978153/how-to-override-a-magento-function-in-app-code-core-mage-core-functions-php

Comment: This is not what i need. I DON'T want to ovverride the whole class. Keep reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/5991786/5065206

Comment: the link which i shared is useful for your answer if you want to use the core functionality with some modification then you need to copy that same file structure in your local why? because we know the magento fallback structure it always go to our local folder first then into core if you use the class then how it will use the local files it always go to core files.

Comment: ok ok, it is not what i need

Comment: then can you please tell us what exactly we are looking for here?so that we can help thanks.

Comment: The right way to override only the roundPrice() function, not the whole class.

Comment: are you able to see your module in admin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same old story

There was another module that already override Mage_Core_Model_Store

So i needed to modify app/etc/modules/MyCompany.xml as follow:

```
<config>
     <modules>
        <MyCompany_RoundPrice>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                 <Other_Module />
            </depends>
       </MyCompany_RoundPrice>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your config.xml has some mistakes. Follow in this way..

```
< ?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <my_core>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </my_core>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
          <core>
              <rewrite>
                  <store>My_Core_Model_Store</Store>
              </rewrite>
          </core>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

and also in the model class, You need to extend the Parent Class Name. For Ex: My_Core_Model_Filename extends Mage_Core_Model_Store

In this way you can override it.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is wrong in my config.xml? I cannot see.

Comment: @krybbio no need to overwrite tag and inner content. Just try it. It will work for me.